# How to find duplicate entries in MySQL then delete all but the highest subvalue

Tags: python, mysql

I kind of understand how to find duplicates but I need to delete all but the one with the highest sub value in a separate row.

```
+------------+---------------+
| ID         | Expiration    |
+------------+---------------+
| 828044 | 5020581708 |
| 586536 | 1672700156 |
| 586536 | 1672700259 |
| 586536 | 1672700300 |
| 828044 | 1672700400 |
+------------+---------------+
```

Again I want to sort by the ID then save the one with the highest Expiration and delete the rest.
Table looks like that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: the suggested duplicate doesn't have answers that fit this question

Comment: Still don't get how to pick the higher Expiration value from the ID's and delete the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a self join to find rows where there's another row that would be kept instead:

```
delete a
from Access as a
join Access as b on b.ID=a.ID and b.Expiration > a.Expiration
```

This will benefit from an index on (ID,Expiration).

Comment: This kind of makes sense but I am pretty new to MySQL. Could you explain how to put this into a command line so I know how to format it in my script? My table name is Access and I'm not sure what to put in place of the a and b you put.

Comment: I have been learning by using things like this:

`INSERT INTO Access VALUES ('828044 ', '1672700259 ');`


Then incorporating that into my normal code.

Comment: you can use a and b or anything else; `tablename as foo` means use tablename but refer to it as foo everywhere else in this query; when you use the same table twice in a query you need to give an alias for at least one of them.

Comment: not sue what you mean about formatting?  it's all just one query, the line breaks just add clarity

Comment: I guess I just typed something wrong then, thank you helped a lot.